# Excel rendering error in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

When I have a matrix in a MSSQL Reporting Serivces report and exports to excel, I sometimes get an error telling me that some cells had to be recovered and and a non-existant /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-del sheet (?)

There's also a link to what I hoped would contain details, but instead was an xml file containing the same message.

How do I find more details to give me a clue as to what was (really) wrong?

I run MS Office 2010, by the way. SSRS runs on a MSSQL 2012, but with a 2005 as datasource.

I hope someone has a good idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the error. I had a divide by zero error. SSRS doesn't say anything, and when you view it in Excel, it just says NaN (Not a Number). But the rendering causes Excel to think there is errors in the file.

Took me a while to find that one - hope it'll help others!